# D3D11 : Rendering onto NV12 texture

Tags: rendering, yuv, direct3d11

MSDN says RTV(render target view) for NV12 texture is supported on hardware feature level 11_1 or above.
And I'm rendering a RGBA texture onto an NV12 texture through two RTVs (R8_UNORM for Y, R8G8_UNORM for UV), while converting colorspace in the pixel shader.

Hmm.. it doesn't work. The possible reasons are
1) the available feature level of my display adapter is 11_0.
2) only the frameworks by MS can use the feature.
3) some configuration on d3d device or context are missing.

BTW, when I built an example of NV12 rendering in MediaElement video effect, it worked well. then I tried to embed my rendering codes into the example (using D3D device in callbacks of the MediaElement video effect).. my codes worked well!

The questions are
1) Does NV rendering work on only MediaElement?
2) Will it work well if I upgrade my display adapter which supports 11_1?
3) Please let me know if there are some configurations I'm missing.